# how to fix database problem that crashes my app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i add a new user but when i try log in with that it crashes my app. It tells me that there is no "name" column. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table users " +
                    "(id integer primary key, name text,password text,age integer)"
    );
    db.execSQL(
            "create table tasks " +
                    "(id integer primary key, name text, agemin integer,agemax integer,time integer)"
    );
}
public boolean insertUser (String name, String password, int age) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("password", password);
    contentValues.put("age", age);
    db.insert("users", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public boolean checkPassword(String name, String password) {
    int id = getUserIDByName(name);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select password from users where id="+id+"", null );
    String pass = res.getString(1);
    return (password.equals(pass));
}

public int getUserIDByName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select id from users where name="+name+"", null );
    int id = res.getInt(1);
    return id;
```

Comment: Post your crash log.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below because it prevents sql injection

```
String query = "select id from users where name=?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String [] {name});
```

but if you want to use raw queries then be sure to put quotes around string values.

Change

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select id from users where name="+name+"", null );
```

to

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select id from users where name='" + name + "'", null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing name in getUserIdbyName() function, you should use colun in query.

```
public int getUserIDByName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select id from users where name='"+name+"'", null );
    int id = res.getInt(1);
    return id;
}
```

integer and numeric datatype easy to compare in SQL when it come to string or Text type its very tricky and bit difficult sometime.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i did what you told me to do but it stil doesnt work. now it tells me "Index -1 requested, with a size of 6"

Answer (score 0):

First use quotes around the `name` variable:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select id from users where name = '"+ name + "'", null );
```

Then change to this:

```
int id = res.getInt(0);
```

and this:

```
String pass = res.getString(0);
```

The indexes of the cursor's columns are `0` based.
Also you must use `moveFirst()` to check if there is any row fetched by the `Cursor`. 
So change to this:

```
public boolean checkPassword(String name, String password) {
    int id = getUserIDByName(name);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select password from users where id="+id+"", null );
    String pass = "";
    if (res.moveFirst())
        pass = res.getString(0);
    return (password.equals(pass));
}

public int getUserIDByName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select id from users where name='"+name+"'", null );
    int id = 0;
    if (res.moveFirst())
        id = res.getInt(0);
    return id;
}
```

Comment: i did what you told me to do but it stil doesnt work. now it tells me "Index -1 requested, with a size of 6"